# TypeScript destructure array of objects, both first object and a value within it

Tags: javascript, typescript, destructuring

I have an array of objects I want to destructure, retrieving both the first object and a value within it:

```
const [{ a }] = ([firstObjectInArray] = [
  {
    a: 1,
  },
  {
    b: 2,
  },
]);
console.log(a); // 1
console.log(firstObjectInArray); // { a: 1 }
```

In Javascript this works; but in TypeScript this returns

```
Cannot find name 'firstObjectInArray'.ts(2304)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to type that in order to avoid the error.

Comment: please have a look to your previous question.

Comment: Why not do it 2 separate destructuring as mentioned in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65354700/): `const [first] = [{ a: 1 }], { a } = first`.

Comment: Please re-read my comment on my previous question

Comment: In the current question, what is the issue with using `const [first] = someArray, { a } = first`?

Comment: The example provided in this question works in Javascript; I'm wondering where the TypeScript error comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `firstObjectInArray` isn't part of your declaration (it's just an expression), it's an assignment to an undeclared variable.

To solve the issue, you have two ways:

- Do it in two steps:

  ```js
  const [firstObjectInArray] = [
      {
        a: 1,
      },
      {
        b: 2,
      },
    ];
  const {a} = firstObjectInArray
  console.log(a); // 1
  console.log(firstObjectInArray); // { a: 1 }
  ```
- Declare the `firstObjectInArray` earlier:

  ```js
  let firstObjectInArray; //<-- This can't be made `const`, as it has no initializer
  const [{ a }] = ([firstObjectInArray] = [
    {
      a: 1,
    },
    {
      b: 2,
    },
  ]);
  console.log(a); // 1
  console.log(firstObjectInArray); // { a: 1 }
  ```

Comment: Dont like any of those solutions, but explains the issue. Thanks.

Comment: The first one *is* the proper solution (and superior to the second). You can even do it in one declaration: `const [firstObjectInArray] = …, {a} = firstObjectInArray;`.

Comment: @Bergi can you elaborate?

Comment: @Bergi I think you are wrong, that's not possible.

Comment: @EmilleC. What do you mean by "not possible"?

Comment: @EmilleC. Any variable declaration (`var`, `let` and `const`) can define any number of variables separated by commas...

Comment: Yes, that was proposed in above; but the question is not about this.

Comment: @EmilleC. I know, just stated that it **is** possible (the thing what Bergi said).